# How to check if specific dictionary is of generic dictionary type in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

The generic dictionary is as follows:

```
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

And specific dictionaries can be as follows:

```
var container = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit>();
var container = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUnitClass>();
```

So, how can I check if some dictionary is of generic dictionary type?

```
object obj = GetObj(); // obj is some of many dictionaries
if(obj is ?)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can you have an instance of a generic class? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

is an 'open generic type', and you cannot have instances of open generic types.

However, if you want to know whether the given object is a dictionary which has generic type parameters, you can use reflection to determine that:

```
        var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string> ();

        var t = d1.GetType ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Generic? " + t.IsGenericType);
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't, but if you really need it for some reason it is:

```
if (obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)) {
    // It is a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
}
```

or

```
if (obj is ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUnitClass>) {
    // It is a ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUsnitClass>
}
```

Comment: First solution works fine. The second one doesn't because I have many ConcurrentDictionary objects with different second parameter.

Comment: And one more question related to the original issue - how can I cast it? Something like: (obj as ConcurrentDictionary<??>).Keys[i]... ?

Comment: You should probably use the non-generic IDictionary interface for that. But I seriously recommend you to rethinkk your design.

Comment: And the last point was left - how to cast object d to generic ConcurrentDictionary:

    ConcurrentDictionary<?, ?> unit = d as ConcurrentDictionary<?, ?>;

I don't want to use specific cast as follows:

    ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit> unit = d as ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit>;

Answer (score 0):

You can also treat the dictionary as a non-generic `IDictionary`. Of course, you loose all strong typing in this case:

```
var dictionary = obj as IDictionary;
if (dictionary != null)
{
    ICollection keys = dictionary.Keys;    
    ICollection values = dictionary.Values;
    // work with keys and values as a collection of objects
}
```